# Setup an auto image compressor on ubuntu vps server running WordPress websites

Tags: wordpress, image-compression

We have a Digital Ocean VPS Server running on Ubuntu 18.04.
We are running multiple Wordpress websites on the server.

We want to auto-compress images when they are uploaded on the website, for example, if add an image into a post or a page or anywhere on the site, the compression should be done on the server side.

I know that it can be accomplished using image compression plugins but tey usually has some problem like:
1. Manually (bulk) optimizing images ( or weekly/daily )
2. Create a copy of the optimized image ( require a lot of space for image heavy website)

I understand that this would be difficult to accomplish since running some image compressor tools to compressor all image and replacing them will eventually lead to a loop to compressor an already compressor image and so on.

I'm trying to find a better approach to store compressed images on the website, which shouldn't be done manually and allow us to delete originally uncompressed with ease.

PS: If this can be done on the server side that would be awesome so we don't have to configure it site to site.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've used jpegoptim for ubuntu server, and wp-smush & reSmush.it for WordPress platform, but as I said in the question. I'm looking for a better approach to compressor images only on upload and then delete the original image. Thanks